# Check for loaded sql object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, preload

My model:

```
class User
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :user

  def self.with_color(color, is_loaded)
    if is_loaded
      self.select { |i| i.color == color }
    else
      self.where(:color => color)
    end
  end

end
```

There are 2 types of code in my controllers.

```
## this line loads 'items' of the user and selects with the red color ##
@colored_items = current_user.items.with_color('red', false)

## this code should not load items twice ##
@user_with_items = User.includes(:items).find(params[:user_id])
(...)
colored_items = @user_with_items.with_color('red', true)
```

If I only write "select" version, it doesnt work with 1 example, and 'where' version loads items again even if they are already loaded.

How can I check is object already loaded or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using scopes?

Taken from example:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :colored, lambda { |color| where(:color => color) }
end
```

More to read here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/scope

With your example, this should be (not tested)

```
class User
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :user
  scope :colored, lambda { |color| where(:color => color) }
end


## this line loads 'items' of the user and selects with the red color ##
@colored_items = current_user.items.colored('red')

## use of 'includes' here to solve (n+1) issue
@user_with_items = User.includes(:items).find(params[:user_id])
colored_items = @user_with_items.colored('red')
```

Update:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def colored_items(color)
    self.items.to_a.select { |i| i.color == color }
  end
end

user = User.includes(:items).find(1)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."user_id" IN (1)
 => #<User id: 1, name: nil, created_at: "2012-03-25 00:39:52", updated_at: "2012-03-25 00:39:52"> 
user.colored_items "red"
 => [#<Item id: 1, color: "red", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-03-25 00:41:00", updated_at: "2012-03-25 00:41:00">] 
user.colored_items "blue"
 => [#<Item id: 2, color: "blue", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-03-25 00:41:04", updated_at: "2012-03-25 00:41:04">]
```

So only 2 SQLs here.

Comment: Scope is the same method as self.colored. Your first example works well, but the second one will execute another query to load only 'red' items. I would do @users_with_items.items.select { |e| e.color == 'red' } instead of scope to use already loaded object.

Comment: Ok, you're right. Scope is doing a SQL everytime. Thought it would handle this. Might be something that could be optimized. So I've added  a possible solution to my answer on top.

Comment: Thanks -). Exactly as I need.